# Storing data locally on the client in AppEngine/GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, store, local

I'm currently developing an application with Appengine and GWT. I have to send a lot of data from an Android phone to the GWT client. My question is, is there a way or an API that I can store or cache this data on the local client?

The data which I'm talking about is just a lot of text from a database from Android. It would be awesome if I could store it somehow that the AppEngine server doesn't have to load the data and send it to the client every time the user connects to my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GWT's [`Storage` API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/storage/client/Storage.html). The application will still need to go to the server if the local copy of your data is deleted or if the browser doesn't support HTML local storage.